# Can a converted woman to Judaism divorce her Gentile husband and marry a Jew?

Tags: divorce

Shalom,

Some time ago I converted to Judaism . I keep the Torah and do not practise pagan   habits and holidays.   My husband is  still Christian. I  am very unhappy in my marriage. My husband treats me very badly . We stopped sleeping together.   I have decided to change my  name too.

Would it be a sin to divorce  him and marry a Jew? I do not want to be an adulteress but maybe in this specific  case divorce will not be prohibited?  Please  give me some advice.

Comment: If you really converted, the Rabbis would have informed you that you are no longer married to your gentile husband. Actually, they wouldn't convert somebody still living with their gentile husband. Spam Bait Alert.

Comment: @DannySchoemann - Don't automatically accuse. Things get very complicated. We don't all the facts of the story. The beis din who did the conversion might also not be Orthodox.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid this site is not the place for personal advice, but we can clear up some misconceptions on Jewish law.

[Deuteronomy 24:1--4](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=5&CHAPTER=24) clearly allows for divorce and remarriage. It says explicitly that Jane could get a divorce from Bob and then go and marry Joe. (She could not, however, subsequently divorce Joe and re-marry Bob; alternatively, if she was still married to Bob and cheated on him with Joe, then got a divorce, she may not marry Joe now. While both of those are prohibited, neither is "adultery" per se. But all of this is far beyond the scope of your question.) **Thus, it would never be "adultery" for a woman to first get divorced from one man, then go meet and marry some other man.**

Judaism makes it clear that divorce is allowed, for all sorts of reasons -- [see Mishna Gittin 9:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Gittin.9?lang=bi), though just because it's allowed doesn't mean it's always the morally best thing to do. Sometimes, though, a couple is absolutely, fundamentally, *what-were-they-thinking* incompatible; [one contemporary senior rabbinic authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter) tells that a mentor of his declared that a congratulatory toast is in order upon handling such a couple's divorce!

If a non-Jew chooses to identify with Judaism and study it, that's great, but a formal conversion ritual requires quite a few steps, the very first one is to go discuss the situation with a rabbi. Until there is a formal conversion, such a person would be considered non-Jewish -- despite all their good intentions -- and thus, a Jewish person would be prohibited from marrying them.

Some people unhappy with their non-Jewish faiths instead identify as [Noahide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noahidism) -- i.e. they do and keep everything that Judaism expects non-Jews to keep, which does not require a conversion.

I hope this background information is helpful as you determine your path forward.